# MMS not being downloaded while roaming?

Tags: android, mms, android-mms

I'm working with the klinker library to receive MMS on Android. Everything is setup correctly but I think I get the following Exception only when I'm roaming. I do have roaming data enabled and with the default messaging app when I receive a MMS I have to click it so it starts downloading. Below are the logs for when I have a roaming sim card in the phone and a local non-roaming sim in the phone

NOT ROAMING

```
03-16 16:00:22.562 8745-8880/sample V/Mms: receiving a new mms message
03-16 16:00:22.715 8745-8880/sample V/Mms: receiving on a lollipop+ device
03-16 16:00:22.742 8745-8880/sample V/DownloadManager: receiving with system method
03-16 16:00:22.770 8745-8880/sample V/Mms: PUSH Intent processed.
03-16 16:00:25.224 8745-8745/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: MMS has finished downloading, persisting it to the database
03-16 16:00:25.224 8745-8745/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: /data/user/0/sample/cache/download.7032006934289480493.dat
03-16 16:00:25.225 8745-8745/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: No MMSC information set, so no notification tasks will be able to complete
03-16 16:00:25.238 8745-8745/sample V/MmsConfig: MmsConfig: mUserAgent=motog4, mUaProfUrl=http://uaprof.motorola.com/phoneconfig/motog4/Profile/motog4.rdf
03-16 16:00:25.243 8745-8745/sample D/MmsConfig: MmsConfig.loadFromResources
03-16 16:00:25.249 8745-8745/sample V/MmsConfig: MmsConfig: all settings -- {smsToMmsTextThreshold=6, httpParams=, maxImageWidth=2592, enabledMMS=true, maxImageHeight=1944, aliasEnabled=false, maxMessageSize=1048576, enableMMSReadReports=false, recipientLimit=20, enabledNotifyWapMMSC=false, maxSubjectLength=80, smsToMmsTextLengthThreshold=-1, enableMMSDeliveryReports=false, uaProfTagName=x-wap-profile, enableMultipartSMS=true, aliasMinChars=2, supportMmsContentDisposition=true, allowAttachAudio=true, sendMultipartSmsAsSeparateMessages=false, maxMessageTextSize=-1, supportHttpCharsetHeader=false, emailGatewayNumber=, enableGroupMms=true, aliasMaxChars=48, httpSocketTimeout=60000, config_cellBroadcastAppLinks=true, userAgent=, naiSuffix=, uaProfUrl=, enableSMSDeliveryReports=true, enabledTransID=false}
03-16 16:00:25.264 8745-8745/sample D/DownloadRequest: DownloadRequest.persistIfRequired
03-16 16:00:25.415 8745-8745/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: response saved successfully
03-16 16:00:25.416 8745-8745/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: response length: 27159
03-16 16:00:25.416 8745-8745/sample D/TEST: MMS CAME IN!!
03-16 16:00:25.416 8745-8745/sample D/TEST: ONRECEIVE CALLED
```

ROAMING

```
03-16 19:28:35.802 14841-14918/sample V/Mms: receiving a new mms message
03-16 19:28:36.112 14841-14918/sample V/Mms: receiving on a lollipop+ device
03-16 19:28:36.148 14841-14918/sample V/DownloadManager: receiving with system method
03-16 19:28:36.184 14841-14918/sample V/Mms: PUSH Intent processed.
03-16 19:36:21.717 14841-14841/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: MMS has finished downloading, persisting it to the database
03-16 19:36:21.717 14841-14841/sample V/MmsReceivedReceiver: /data/user/0/sample/cache/download.4066077938203007033.dat
03-16 19:36:21.719 14841-14841/sample E/MmsReceivedReceiver: MMS received, file not found exception
                                                                                              java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/sample/cache/download.4066077938203007033.dat (No such file or directory)
                                                                                                  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
                                                                                                  at MmsReceivedReceiver.onReceive(MmsReceivedReceiver.java:96)
                                                                                                  at com.klinker.android.messaging_sample.MmsReceived.onReceive(MmsReceived.java:14)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3032)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1557)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
03-16 19:36:21.719 14841-14841/sample D/TEST: ONRECEIVE CALLED
```